# FTDI Chip Windows Error Message "USB device attached malfunctioned and windows does not recognize." Design Error?

Tags: usb, ftdi, error, windows

My PCB has a FT230XS-R USB to UART communicating with an AVR chip. My first prototype board worked perfectly except for the USB problem stated in post title. I triple checked everything. Can NOT find why I'm getting this error. This may be a design flaw on my side? I followed the "Self-Powered" configuration on page 23 in the [datasheet](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/163/DS_FT230X-5395.pdf) exactly as displayed.

Things I have checked:

Solder bridging?: Everything is reflow soldered, I still checked under microscope, it's perfect.

Still used a MM to check for shorts: None.

Checked cable: Good

Power supply quality: < 2mV peak to peak

Correct USB connector pins go to correct inputs: Yes

I triple checked the pinout on the datasheet against my PCB: Everything's correct.

I checked ground, VCC, and VCCIO values. Everything's normal.

I remade a PCB, I left every component unpopulated except for the FTDI chip and 
peripheral components needed to run the chip. Still had the same problem.

I tried removing RX and TX LEDs: Nothing.

I then removed 47pF caps and 27 ohm resistors: Nothing.

I am at a loss. I contacted FTDI. They only said I have a short somewhere, and they asked for a schematic. I sent them the schematic, never heard back from them.

Could vias on my USB signal lines be corrupting the signal? Any info is greatly appreciated. I uploaded only relevant schematics and PCB design snapshot.

Please ignore U9 and pads directly above it, they are unpopulated. They were never populated for either test.

Thank you so much.

[image: PCB Design]

[image: Schematic]

Comment: Are you confident with the FTDI chips supplier? They're so popular there must be plenty of fakes out there.

Comment: Your schematic does not tell the whole story, as the layout shows. On the schematic, I see pin 3 of J4 going directly to pin 8 of U5. On the layout instead, I see the tracks going through the RC as per the datasheet. I also see a U9 connected to D+ and D-, what is that about? Please, post a complete and correct schematic if you want help.

Comment: How is the FTDI chip powered? Is it meant to be bus powered because your cct isnt

Comment: The schematic and layout don't match.

Comment: These boards can have Windows and Linux and Android drivers, but not likely all 3. Are you certain of the drivers installed?

Comment: I got the chip from Mouser, so there's no issues with counterfeit. AH yes I'm sorry, this is an older schematic! I was in such a hurry last night. Yes D+ and D- both go through an RC as per the datasheet and can be seen on the layout. U9 is a suppressor  diode. I left it unpopulated. My board was power by a 600kHZ buck converter. But this is not the issue, when I remade the 2nd board, I left all power components off and powered the board directly from my bench power supply.

Comment: I updated to the correct schematic

Comment: You should use physically smaller passives and put the whole input circuit in a row without that nasty branch down to your clamp diode.  Route manually with preference for key signals, for example there's no real need to swap sides on the USB pair.  Use a groundplane on the back in general.

Comment: Also it looks like your USB signal ground is unconnected!

Comment: Chris Stratton:  The USB signals will need to still cross at some point. The D+ & - on connector side are opposite with the chip side. That branching is very ugly. I did this because I wanted to test functionality with clamp diode. The datasheet mentions no use of clamp diodes so I wanted to be sure it works before rearranging the board. Funny thing, I actually had the Silicone Labs chip on here which was MUCH smaller. I had the same exact problem. But they don't make a leaded package. I figured some pins were shorted under the chip where I couldn't see, that's why I swapped for the FTDI.

Comment: Routing is ugly because it was originally designed around the Silicone Labs chip. No sir, the USB signal ground is connected to board ground. I have a solid copper ground plane on the top and bottom, I just turned it off so everyone can see trace paths

Comment: Chris, do you think that 0805 package and trace routing is causing the problem?

Comment: Another note to add, I will only be using USB to communicate relatively slow baud rates < 57600. Definitely no high speed communication happening

Comment: You don't have many vias to stitch your planes together, ground may have a bad route. Your series resistors provide an opportunity to swap sides.  Your USB communication is at 12 megabits/second regardless of the rate at which you do or do not utilize it to move proxied serial traffic.  Try plugging it into a linux box (a raspberry pi would do, a VM would not) and running dmesg where you'll get a more detailed failure message.  Also try it with/without a hub, on a different port, etc.  Probe the USB signals with a scope; you'll likely cause failures but you can see if there is any activity...

Comment: Well I didn't show the whole board. This is a much larger board than shown. I have many vias in other places. Plus that large through hole to the left of the "status" is a hole for a mounting screw, there are 6 of them on the board. The very large plating is on the top and bottom layers is connected to ground. Would you still think I need ground vias closer to this chip? Ah, excellent. I have a raspberry pi, I'll try that. I already confirmed I have activity on the signal lines

Comment: Yes, you need vias closer.  Think about how indirect the path of your chip's bypass capacitor currently is.  You want something like that to be as short as possible on *both* positive and negative connections, as it will see pulse current at the edges of the clock required for the USB engine, ie it is basically an RF circuit.

Comment: There is something strange with pins 10, 11, and pin3 on your picture. They should be connected together. Are they?